# Angular 5 - Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<any>'

Tags: angular

I am just writing a simple Angular experiment and I am getting the following error... `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<any>'` I am trying to load static json data from a data file through a service into a component. I am not sure why this is happening as I have done this many times before, here is my Angular service...

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   }

    public getDashboardData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('../../data/dashboard-data.json');
    }
}
```

nothing strange here... now let's look at my Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.getDashboardData.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

I can't see what is wrong? I've done this so many times before. The JSON in the static file is valid and linted. I must be missing something very simple but I can't understand or see what I am doing wrong. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`getDashboardData()`** is a function not a variable, You need to change it as,

```
   this.dashboardService.getDashboardData().subscribe((result) => {
          console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: Oh my! Facepalm moment... it's been a long day!